# How to resolve the "java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have below code and I observed SQL exception as below:

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called

Code:

```
String query = "select account_number,flag,flag2,flag3,flag4,flag5,flag6,flag7,amount from transaction_p2 where account_number=?";

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1,"2195281819521610731");

boolean rs = ps.execute();

if(rs)
{
    ResultSet set=ps.getResultSet();
    System.out.pringln(set+"\t resultset");
    System.out.println(set.getInt("amount"));
}
else
{
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

output:

```
Connecting database...
Database connected!
oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@55dbe543 resultset
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:565)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:1350)
    at com.online.paypal.getSampleConnection.SampleTestConnection.main(SampleTestConnection.java:48)
```

I just get the Resultset value that I'm printing in the `system.out.println(set);` but when I tried to get the value it throws the SQL exception. I'm not sure how can I get the value from result set.

Please let me know how can I get the value from the result set and how to overcome this issue.

If I use `while(set.next())` I don't see anything in the output console. And it returned false.

Comment: by... calling next()?

Comment: I called next(). But It's returning false. And nothing is printing.

Comment: That, once again, means that the query returned no row at all. You can't possibly get any value from a row if there is no row.

Comment: But if you see the above code it prints the ResultSet in console. But not sure how to get the value.

Comment: Once again, you can't get any value from an empty resultset. Accept it: your query returns no row. So there is no transaction_p2 in your table with the given account number. It doesn't exist. You get a resultset, but it's empty. Just like you can have a bottle with nothing inside the bottle. You're trying to drink from an empty bottle.

Comment: I just query but records are available for that account number.

Comment: No no record is available, otherwise the query wouldn't return an empty resultset. So either you inserted the records but never committed the transaction, or you're looking at a different table, or a different schema, or a different database, or you're just making a mistake.

Comment: Then how do we get this reuslt in output console : oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@55dbe543 resultset. the connectivity is correct and I cross check that.

Comment: That's your result set. And it's empty. Just like you can have a bottle which is empty. Or a sheet which is blank.The result set exists and can be printed, but there is nothing inside it.

Comment: *"I called next(). But It's returning false."* Then edit the question and show us the code where you do that. --- Also, you know you're running a `SELECT` statement, so don't call `ps.execute()` then `ps.getResultSet()`. Instead, simply call `ps.executeQuery()`. --- And use try-with-resources to make sure the JDBC objects are closed correctly.